# Karate - To find the occurrence of element in a list and print the number of times its present in the list

Tags: cucumber, karate, bdd, gherkin

In my case

list A = [a,a,a,b,b,c]

I have to find the occurrence of the elements available in the list and print their counts

For example print as a=3, b =2 and c =1

Comment: kindly refer how to ask good questions and try again, note that you can edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I hope solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685181/karate-trying-print-the-number-of-occurrence-of-element-in-the-list-dynamicall/72861094#72861094 might meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript. The `filter()` operation is perfect for this:

```
* def data = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
* def count = data.filter(x => x == 'c').length
* assert count == 3
```

Further reading: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

Comment: Thankyou. But how to do it when the values are dynamic in the list?

Comment: @VigneshGangatharaRao what you are asking is a javascript question. first find out how to get all values. then loop over all values and run the filter operation