# Karate - Trying print the number of occurrence of element in the list dynamically

Tags: javascript, filter, cucumber, karate

I am trying to get the count of multiple occurrence of the element present in the list dynamically which is created from the response element of the API

Here i am trying using the filter method, by filtering the element from the list and finding out their count

**Scenario :**

- def list = karate.jsonPath(response,"$..item.id") // creating a list from the response
- print list
- def fun = function(c){ return (x => x == c ).length } // Function to get the count
- def res = karate.filter(list, fun) // using filter method
- print res

I have executed this scenario, but I getting failed, count was returned as empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682986/karate-to-find-the-occurrence-of-element-in-a-list-and-print-the-number-of-tim/72684335#72684335
I think you can be able to find the answer here

Comment: @VigneshGangatharaRao, i need to check the dynamic list which i created using the response of API request

Comment: provide a clear example, edit your question if needed. right now I can't understand it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterThomas i have edited the question . please help me out

Comment: sorry, I still can't understand. read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. This will take list / array as argument and prints the elements with number of occurrences. Since there is no sample list in the original question, i tried with one generic example. Let me know whether it works or not.

```
* def data = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
* def countNoOfCharsUsingMap = 
"""
function(arg){
    var tempMap = {};
    arg.forEach((c) =>{
    if(!tempMap[c]) tempMap[c] = 1
    else{
        var cnt = tempMap[c]
        tempMap[c] = cnt+1
    }
})
karate.log(tempMap);
}
"""
* countNoOfCharsUsingMap(data)
```

Comment: i am getting the answer for above as a:1 ,b: 1, c:3 ,d :1 , now i need to split up the alphabets and number. How to implement the split up in the karate.log functionality

Comment: @MuthukannandoodleblueQAEngi You don't need to split the final value again. All you have to do is run a loop on the **tempMap** using the unique values to get each character & it's occurance. Something like below should work without any issues.       
`let uniqueChars = [...new Set(arg)]    
uniqueChars.forEach((c) =>{
 karate.log('Character '+ c +' found '+ tempMap[c]+' times')
})`

Comment: i have doubt def count = {
cb1bdc8b-4b53-43b8-b4c2-00638dc1d7df=2,   
55d0c09c-8838-4b63-9651-70b2bb1baa15=2,    
78f46729-d674-486f-849d-2f40a0591313=2, 
634ea784-f4a6-4d02-8cda-0374e53823d6=1, 
}  How to split the elements in the list as "634ea784-f4a6-4d02-8cda-0374e53823d6" and "1" using split method in karate